If managed package retires, can they "pull" the managed objects or other managed elements?
If a vendor stops managing a package, it was my understanding that the objects remained in the installed org unaffected (without future updates etc).  But can the vendor somehow remove/disable the managed elements from an org?
Usecase includes only objects installed into SF, not external API integrations.
(I can't see how they'd even reach in to do that... but want to be clear)

to be clear this includes installed apex automations, VF pages and (old style) workflows


But can the vendor somehow remove/disable the managed elements from an org?

A vendor can expire a client's license(s) in the LMA, which will disable the app. However, the metadata can't be removed by the vendor. It would be up to the client to uninstall the app. The reason why there's no automatic uninstall feature that the vendor can use is because it could break client orgs. For example, a client could have built a trigger on a custom object in the package. If the custom object were removable, the trigger would fail, potentially causing showstopping problems.

Thanks! Wondering what "disable the app" means in this context  :
usecase - there is data in the custom objects.  So the custom objects would continue and the data would remain?
Would automations (using apex) stop working? or continue because the Apex remains?
Maybe my question is what STOPS working when the app is "disabled"

@Blueiris Actually, I may be wrong. I can't seem to find it in the documentation, but this Q&A shows that, at least in 2016, everything will just be removed. Or maybe that was special circumstances because the entire org was removed? It's hard to tell.

Darn.  Really need to understand!
